# SQl query to get table based on date difference

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a table with user information, there is a created_date field based on that i have to select some data from the table.

first i have take current date and i need to fetch data before three days. I mean i have to fetch data greeter than 3 days date difference between current date and created_date.

this is my table structure

```
fb_requests  CREATE TABLE `fb_requests` (                                              
               `id` int(60) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                   
               `user_id` int(60) DEFAULT NULL,                                         
               `fb_user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,                                 
               `request_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,                                 
               `game_selected` int(60) DEFAULT NULL,                                   
               `accept_status` int(60) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 = pending 1 = accept',  
               `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,                                   
               `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,                                  
               PRIMARY KEY (`id`)                                                      
             ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=157 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[image]

struggling to write a query for that, please help me to solve this issue, Thanks in advance

Comment: Struggling with that? But that's easy. Stop. Step away from the machine. Have a coffee. Think. And try again.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a trivial issue covered by numerous questions on this site, and shows no effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from fb_request where created_date>now()-3;
```

And for 3 days instead of 72 hours (!) use this one:

```
select * from fb_request where created_date>date(now())-3;
```

Tip: look for a SQL introduction course and read it...

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. select *  from fb_requests where created_date>date(now())- 3 using this query am getting results within that 3 days range, my requirement is to get record other than this, i mean to get records outside the range of these three days only.

Comment: Thanks i put a not after where clause and get correct result. Thank you so much for your help